# angularjs reorder ng repeat results based on given array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm learning Angularjs and I have a small question:

I have the following array returned from user

```
userPreferences = [7,5,4]
```

I have an object that I'm using ng-repeat to display all news and looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "preferences": [
      3,
      4
    ]
}
```

So, I want to use in my ng-repeat, the array returned from user preferences, and sort the news displaying the preferences first, then below the other news, is that possible?

Something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="new in news | filter:{'userPreferences' : new.preferences}">
```

I don't really know if I have to use filter, orderBy or sort, any help please?

Comment: So if `new.preferences` array has **all** the elements of `userPreferences`, you want to show them is it?

Comment: Yes, but like, new.preferences has category 3 and 4, and userPreferences has 3, this new will be displayed first and all the others below it. like, sorting by relevance i think

Comment: You want to display all the new's too which don't match the user preference?

Comment: Yeah, bellow the ones that matchs, i just don't know if that's possible and how to achieve this.

Comment: In above sample object ,news.preferences is 3,4,show how you going to display it,Where this id belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your own function that returns the number of the matched `preferences` on your scope:

```
function intersect(array1, array2) {
    return $filter('filter')(array1, function(n){
    return array2.indexOf(n) != -1;
  });
}

$scope.matchedPreferences = function(n) {
    return intersect(n.preferences, $scope.userPreferences).length;
};
```

and pass it to `orderBy` filter:

```
<li ng-repeat="n in news | orderBy:matchedPreferences:true">{{n}}</li>
```

This will order the news by the number of matched preferences in the descending order.

Here the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnw42ytb/1/)